# Convert encryption from AesCryptoServiceProvider to BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes, bouncycastle

I have file on disk encrypted with `AesCryptoServiceProvider`.
I need to convert the code to PCL (which doesn't have the class `AesCryptoServiceProvider`). So i would like to use Bouncy Castle ( https://www.nuget.org/packages/Portable.BouncyCastle/ ) to read and save files without changing the encryption. And prevent the need to convert all the files..

`Key` is 32 bytes long.
`IV` is 16 bytes long.

Here is the original code :

```
private static byte[] Encrypt(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
    using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesAlg = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        aesAlg.Key = Key;
        aesAlg.IV = IV;

        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
        using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(outputStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                {
                    swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                }
            }

            return outputStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

The default mode of `AesCryptoServiceProvider` is `CBC` with a padding of type `PKCS7`, then i tried with classes `CbcBlockCipher` and `Pkcs7Padding`. Here is my last try :

```
private static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] input, byte[] key, byte[] IV)
{
    var keyParameter = new KeyParameter(key);
    var parameters = new ParametersWithIV(keyParameter, IV);

    var cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CbcBlockCipher(new AesEngine()), new Pkcs7Padding());

    cipher.Init(true, parameters);

    var rsl = new byte[cipher.GetOutputSize(input.Length)];
    var outOff = cipher.ProcessBytes(input, 0, input.Length, rsl, 0);

    cipher.DoFinal(rsl, outOff);
    return rsl;
}
```

The original result for text "test" is `8jykPv2OSILKjJwvgLRr1w==`, but with new code is `BaYeiuWSnRiHXBpwt19Dag==` .

Then what i miss?

Thanks for your help!

**Update #1 :**
Here is the value for Key and IV :

```
private static byte[] KEY = {98, 193, 95, 78, 211, 151, 118, 57, 179, 5, 85, 181, 133, 20, 94, 101, 184, 175, 94, 164, 150, 119, 75, 207, 189, 178, 21, 213, 13, 217, 174, 44};
private static byte[] IV = {1, 199, 179, 189, 160, 220, 229, 238, 179, 14, 255, 147, 187, 49, 179, 134 };
```

**Update #2 :**
For Bouncy Castle, I convert my `plainText` to `input` with this line :

```
var input = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText);
```

The difference come from there...

Comment: what are the key and IV?

Comment: @JamesKPolk : Values added!

Comment: Can you take the opportunity to replace the encryption by secure encryption? The existing one is rather weak since it uses a constant IV (completely missing the point of an IV) and lacks a MAC.

Comment: @CodesInChaos : The constant was only for the test. I tried to convert the code, so i use this constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before calling the Encrypt() method using BouncyCastle, I converted my string with `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText);` instead of `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);`

With this fix, both method give the same result!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the encoding of the streamwriter. when writing to the cryptostream it brings the same result:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void windows()
    {

        byte[] KEY = { 98, 193, 95, 78, 211, 151, 118, 57, 179, 5, 85, 181, 133, 20, 94, 101, 184, 175, 94, 164, 150, 119, 75, 207, 189, 178, 21, 213, 13, 217, 174, 44 };
        byte[] IV = { 1, 199, 179, 189, 160, 220, 229, 238, 179, 14, 255, 147, 187, 49, 179, 134 };

        byte[] input = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test");

        string win = Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt_win(input, KEY, IV));

        string bc = Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt_bc(input, KEY, IV));



        Assert.AreEqual(win, "8jykPv2OSILKjJwvgLRr1w==");
        Assert.AreEqual(bc, "8jykPv2OSILKjJwvgLRr1w==");

    }


    //private static byte[] Encrypt(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    private static byte[] Encrypt_win(byte[] input, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesAlg = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;


            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
            using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(outputStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    csEncrypt.Write(input, 0, input.Length);

                    /*
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        //swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        swEncrypt.Write(input);
                    }
                    */
                }

                return outputStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }



    private static byte[] Encrypt_bc(byte[] input, byte[] key, byte[] IV)
    {
        var keyParameter = new KeyParameter(key);
        var parameters = new ParametersWithIV(keyParameter, IV);

        var cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CbcBlockCipher(new AesEngine()), new Pkcs7Padding());

        cipher.Init(true, parameters);

        var rsl = new byte[cipher.GetOutputSize(input.Length)];
        var outOff = cipher.ProcessBytes(input, 0, input.Length, rsl, 0);

        cipher.DoFinal(rsl, outOff);
        return rsl;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem wasn't the StreamWriter. But your answer help me to found the problem! I converted my string with             `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText);` instead of `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);`